# Add a link to the logo on the maintenance page

Tags: feature-request, offline, maintenance

The logo on the [maintenance page](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm) (the one with the nice `Meta Means Murder`) does not link against the site, I think it should do that so that we can use it as a cheap `Refresh` alternative (to try if it works again).

Comment: Uh, which one doesn't link back to the site for you? Either they already did, or this has *just* been fixed...

Comment: @Cody Gray: Arrr...I meant the maintenance page. Going to fix my question.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/error) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/404) (and their Meta equivalents) both have active logo links.

Comment: @Cody Gray: There it is! You're my hero! :)

Comment: By definition, app_offline means that there is a good chance the link will fail... also: note that you might see this on "meta" more than other places, due to different infrastructure/configuration of meta/everything-else. Not sure this is critical...?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: This is absolutely *not* critical in any way, it's just something I just stumbled upon (seeing the error page my first intention was to click the logo to retry).

Comment: You could also argue that [F5] already does everything a link would, and avoids the issue of going to the wrong page afterwards

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Yes, I'm aware of that. I tried to express that with the `cheap refresh alternative` part.